# 2004 Powerstroke diesel no power in gear

Tags: ford, diesel, power-loss

2004 6l super duty was running fine when I had an oil leak on the high pressure oil sensor, truck sat for a year plus,(disabled vet)

Finally got the sensor replaced and the engine starts fine, will ramp up 3k rpm in park sounds fine no engine codes idles fine, but put it in drive or reverse and no power, it has fresh oil oil filter and fuel filters. I let it run at 1500 to 2k rpm for 1/2 hour to heat things up if sitting was the issue, no smoke, everything sounds good to me but under load I can’t get any rpm’s.
It was running fine prior to the oil leak I have looked to make sure I did not disconnect anything but have not found anything wrong any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> under load I can’t get any rpm’s

Sort of like you're pressing on the brake pedal while gunning the engine?

Are the brakes frozen / rusted in place? See if you can get the vehicle to move at all. You can bump it gently with another vehicle to see if it moves while in neutral with parking brake off.

Comment: I can move it I only have about 100 yards of driveway I can get it to 15 mph , just like no power no check engine light went back but like it was running on 2 cylinder but no shaking no missing no power I tried it again and same thing if I hit the brakes it stops fine both forward and reverse,